# Dynamically choose dependency without if else

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns, dependency-injection

How can i choose dependency without if else condition.

Suppose i have a interface:

```
public interface A{

String doSomething(String req);
}
```

there are two service implements `A`:

```
@Component
public class FirstImpl implements A{

   @override
   String doSomething(String req){
   return "something";
  }
}
```

and:

```
@Component
public class SecondImpl implements A{

 @override
    String doSomething(String req){
    return "something";
  }
}
```

Now i create a AdapterService class:

```
@Component
public class AdapterService{
    @Autowired
    private FirstImpl first;
    @Autowired
    private SecondImpl second;

    public getService(String name){
        if("name".equals("First")){
            return first;
        }else if("name".equals("Second")){
            return second;
        }
    }
}
```

Now call Implementation:

```
@Service
public class BusinessService{
    @Autowired
    private AdapterService adapterService;

    void doSomething(String name,String req){
        return adapterService.getService(name).doSomething();
    }
}
```

Now if i need to create another class which implements A then need to add condition in ServiceAdapter class. Like `"Third".equals(name)` return another injected service. For every new service there need to add another if else condition and inject corresponding service. How can i avoid this Adapter class. Spring dynamically choose depenedency from name.

Comment: If you have access to applicationContext object, you can call applicationContext.getBean(name) and totally avoid the ServiceAdapter class. Only thing is you need to have those beans in the container.

Comment: @RishikeshDhokare is absolutely right if you can name your beans same as your code is expecting or else just create a function in `A` called getName(). Then in your `BusinessService` class you can inject `List<A>` and create a `Map<String,A>` out of it.

Comment: why create Map<String,A> ?

Comment: you dont get his solution.

Comment: @rishikeshdhokare thanks. it works

Comment: @sajib i am converting that into an answer in case someone else faces the same question. Please accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to `applicationContext` object, you can call

> applicationContext.getBean(name)

and totally avoid the ServiceAdapter class. Only thing is you need to have those beans in the container.

Try with this:

```
@Component
public class AdapterService{
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public A getService(String name){
        return applicationContext.getBean(name,A.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the [java SPI, Service Provider Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html), see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html), would do just as well, as trying to use the Spring hammer.

For an interface `x.y.z.A` there is a discovery mechanism of implementing classes using the java SPI.

You can have several jars.

They have a text file `META-INF/services/x.y.z.A` with implementing class(es) on a line not starting with `#`.

As you might not want to instantiate a object of the class before it is selected by name you would either use a runtime annotation on the class, or have the SPI on a
factory AFactory with minor construction overhead, creating an A.

```
ServiceLoader<Dictionary> loader = ServiceLoader.load(A.class);
Iterator<A> dictionaries = loader.iterator();
```

Comment: tnx for your reply. `applicationContext.getBean(name)` works also

Comment: @sajib thanks, that would indeed be the simplest solution; and then check on the interface A. However if the providers of interface A must be searched for, then SPI is useful. SPI does not need a bean for every class, but that is a very minor issue.