# Spring MVC - how to load/inject service dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

For my Spring MVC application, I will have a controller which will handle all requests from paths say `service/*`.
urls can be like 
`/service/item/getitems`,
`/service/property/getproperties`

The controller will have to load the service class at runtime based on the url specified. For example, if url is `/service/item/getitems`, the controller should load `itemService` and should be able to call `itemService.getItems();`
if the url is `/service/property/getproperties`, it should load `propertyService` and call `propertyService.getProperties()`

How can I implement the run time (dynamic) loading of services from controller?

Comment: Hi, Why not create two routes inside your Controller class and invoke different functions of same service or autowire different services and invoke them inside different routes like here : https://www.journaldev.com/21536/spring-restcontroller. Inside Controller, they have defined severals Get and Post routes which share same suffix URL and call different services.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically choose dependency without if else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51718836/dynamically-choose-dependency-without-if-else)

Answer (score 0):

`application.yml` should look like this

```
server:
  port: 8090
  servlet:
    context-path: /service
```

`ApiController.java` should look like this

```java
public abstract class ApiController<Id extends Serializable, E> {

    /**
     * Collection for service classes.
     *
     * @see AbstractService
     */
    private final AbstractService<Id, E> service;
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

 public ApiController(AbstractService<Id, E> service) {
        this.service = service;
    }
    }
```

`AbstractService.java` should look like this

```java
public interface AbstractService<Id extends Serializable, E> {

    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    public default Class<E> getEntityClass() {
        return (Class<E>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[1];

    }
```

`ItemController.java` should look like this

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/item")
public class ItemController extends ApiController<Integer, Item> {


private final ItemService itemService;

@Autowired
    public ItemController(ItemService service) {
    super(service);
    this.service = service;
    }
}
```

`PropertyController.java` should look like this

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/property")
public class PropertyController extends ApiController<Integer, Property> {


private final PropertyService propertyService;

@Autowired
    public PropertyController(propertyService service) {
    super(service);
    this.service = service;
    }
}
```

That's what you need to do, in order to get desired results.

Comment: @Peter if this could help you do tell me. Otherwise, if you want to do generics in order to get desired results. Feel free to tell me ok

Comment: I can have only one controller. Service should be loaded dynamically based on the url

Comment: Take the idea from above you can easily do this stuff through generics @Peter